# Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1 in Tailwindcss

Tags: deployment, tailwind-css, vercel

After putting the project on GitHub
It cannot be deployed in Vercel
And I got the following error:

> Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1

Answer (score 0):

friends,
After a lot of searching, I finally solved my problem. It was because:

- My script for building the project was (npm run dev), while Vercel deploys such projects with the (npm run build) command.
- You should also pay attention to the public folder inside your project, Because it may have another name.